# Convert part of C# datacolumn to linear string

Tags: c#, string, dynamic, datacolumn

I am having below datatable,

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| one | This is one |
| two | This is two |
| three | This is three |
| four | This is four |

my flow will receive parameter as "one", "two", "three" or "four" and based on this parameter, output string should be like below,

If "one" is parameter then output string -> This is one 
If "two" is parameter then output string -> This is one, This is two 
If "four" is parameter then output string -> This is one, This is two, This is three, This is four

Above can be achieved using loop but wanted to checked if there can be a better way of doing it(using linq?).

For simplicity I updated datatable with simple strings(one, two..etc). However in actual case, data table will have random strings. My requirement would be like below.

"If the passed parameter is in nth row of column 1, then result would be column2(row 1) +","+ column2(row 2)+"," +......+","+column2(row n)."

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried till now? Does datatable contains only those thwo columns?

Comment: are you expecting any pattern?

Comment: Apologies for not being precise. For simplicity I updated datatable with simple strings(one, two..etc). However in actual case, data table will have random strings. My requirement would be like this --> if the passed parameter is in nth row of column 1, then result would be column2(row 1) +","+ column2(row 2)+"," +......+","+column2(row n). And datatable will have only two columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear, but...

Assuming that you've got datatable with 2 columns type of string, then you need to find index of row with `parameter` equals to `Column1` and return concatenated string from `Column2`.

```
string parameter = "four";

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[]
    {
        new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("Column2", typeof(string))
    });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[]{"one", "string related to 'one'"});
dt.Rows.Add(new object[]{"two", "string related to 'two'"});
dt.Rows.Add(new object[]{"three", "string related to 'three'"});
dt.Rows.Add(new object[]{"four", "string related to 'four'"});

DataRow row = dt.Select($"Column1 = '{parameter}'").First();
if(row==null) return;
int pos = dt.Rows.IndexOf(row);
string result = string.Join("; ", dt.AsEnumerable()
    .TakeWhile((x, y) => y<=pos)
    .Select(x =>x.Field<string>("Column2")));
    
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Grid View where you are checking

`this is One`

You can Simple do
`This is`  and then print One two three from DB by counting Length

Hope this is the best technique and easy technique

Comment: Apologies for not being precise. For simplicity I updated datatable with simple strings(one, two..etc). However in actual case, data table will have random strings. My requirement would be like this --> if the passed parameter is in nth row of column 1, then result would be column2(row 1) +","+ column2(row 2)+"," +......+","+column2(row n)

Comment: You need to put some code for further assistance of your question next time